# Next.JS fetch not memoizing in the same request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, fetch-api, next.js13

I have a simple set up, a Next.JS server side component which fetches a post and then displays the post. The page title needs to be set to the title of the post. I have to call my posts API endpoint twice: once in the `generateMetadata` and once in the component itself.

According to [Next.JS's documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating#fetching-data-on-the-server-with-fetch), `fetch` requests are memoized during the entire request. When testing locally, for me, this is not the case, I can see in my API logs that the API endpoint is being hit twice.
What is the correct way to get the `fetch` memoization to work? Below is my (simplified) component code:

```
// posts/[slug]/page.tsx

import {Metadata} from "next";
import {PostResponse} from "@/service/model/api";

export async function generateMetadata(props: PostPageProps): Promise<Metadata> {
    const response = await fetch(`${process.env.BASE_URL}/api/posts/slug?slug=${props.params.slug}`, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Authorization": `Bearer ${process.env.API_KEY}`
        },
    });

    const posts: PostResponse = await response.json();

    return {
        title: posts.posts[0].title
    }
}

export default async function PostPage(props: PostPageProps) {
    const response = await fetch(`${process.env.BASE_URL}/api/posts/slug?slug=${props.params.slug}`, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Authorization": `Bearer ${process.env.API_KEY}`
        },
    });
    const posts: PostResponse = await response.json();

    return (<div>
               <p>{posts.posts[0].title}</p>
           </div>);

}

export interface PostPageProps {
    params: PostPageParams;
}

interface PostPageParams {
    slug: string;
    text?: string;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Okay, I've figured it out.**

As it turns out, Next.JS/React does not do the memoization of the fetch() calls when running in development mode / locally.

Once I make a production build and use that one, the memoization is working correctly and only one request hits my API endpoint.

As to why... I have no idea, but it should be documented better in the Next.JS documentation.